# ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Gmaps4rails address Address invalid error when Trying to import CSV to model with gmaps4rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, gmaps4rails

I'm importing a thousand record csv to a model that has gmap4rails geocoding.  The import keeps failing after a dozen or so records, but always on a different record.  The data doesn't seem bad, as it has imported a record on one try, and then failed on that same record on another. Here's the model code:

```
require 'csv'

  validates :name, :uniqueness  => true
  validates :address, :presence  => true
  acts_as_gmappable
  def gmaps4rails_address
    "#{self.address} New Orleans, LA #{self.zip}"
      rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid  
        print "err"
        end


  def self.import_restaurants()

    CSV.foreach('lib/uploads/NOLA_Restaurants_Basic.csv', :headers => true) do |row|
        record = Restaurant.new(
            :name     => row[0], 
            :address  => row[1], 
            :zip      =>  row[2], 
        )
        if record.address.valid?
          record.save!  

        end
    end
  end
```

I'm running 
    Restaurant.import_restaurants() from the console.

A few sample lines of the CSV

```
name    address zip
ORLEANS CLUB    5005  ST CHARLES AVE    70115
LOUISIANA CLUB  707  UNION ST   70130
HOTEL MONTELEONE    214  ROYAL ST   70130
N O LAWN TENNIS CLUB    5353  LAUREL ST 70115
DOMILISES BAR   5240  ANNUNCIATION ST   70115
```